# CSS custom property priority

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm learning CSS.

I'm trying to have a header style change when I scroll and figuring out the best way to do it.

Just a few questions

1. Are ladder defined CSS properties the final properties that are rendered on the DOM?
2. If 1 is true, do custom CSS properties override previously declared CSS properties?

[My code](https://codepen.io/dplumbonline/pen/MWmyvYG)

Summary;

I've defined a header element.

```
header {--justify-content: center; justify-content: var(--justify-content);}
```

On scroll, I'll use .js to add this class in order to modify the properties.

```
.header-scrolled {--justify-content: "space-between";}
```

Is this valid code?

Thank you.

Comment: you have to remove the `"`

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Thanks (:. Although, without that, the issue is still the same.